# Generate All Strings of ‘n’ bits. Assume A[0….n-1] be an array of size n

Tags: recursion

```
void binary(int n)
{
    if(n < 1)
        printf("%s\n",A);    // Assume A is a global variable
    else
    {
        A[n-1] = '0';
        binary(n-1);
        A[n-1] = '1';
        binary(n-1);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain the stack frames for `n =` 2? I mean when `n = 2`, I'm getting `00` when I'm doing a dry run. But there is also a `01` which I'm missing. Can someone please explain what stack frames are generated for this code?

Comment: Please [edit] your code show the declaration of `A`, and also include your language (C?) in the tags.

Comment: This code seems correct. Can you add the output you get?

Comment: @EarlGray i am getting 00 and 11.But there will be other values like 01,10 which I am unable to generate using this program.

Answer (score 10):

Let us try to understand the code.

```
if(n < 1)
    printf("%s\n",arr);
else
{
    arr[n-1] = '0';
    binary(n-1);
    arr[n-1] = '1';
    binary(n-1);
}
```

We will follow a backwards approach since it is a recursive function.For instance lets say `n = 1`,

The method is called as `binary(1);`
`arr[n-1]` is set as `‘0’` `(arr[1-1] = arr[0] = ‘0’)`

Now we call `binary(0);`
since `(n<1)` we print `arr` (0 is printed)

The call returns to `arr[n-1] = ‘1’`
`arr[1-1]` is set as ‘1’ `(arr[1-1] = arr[0] = ‘1’)`

Now we call `binary(0);`
since `(n<1)` we print `arr` (1 is printed)

Thus, we got 2 outputs as possible bits `0` and `1`.

Now let us suppose `n = 2`,

The method is called as `binary(2)`
`arr[2-1]` is set as ‘0’ `(arr[2-1] = arr[1] = ‘0’)`

Now we call `binary(1);`
From the above explanation we know that `binary(1)` produces an output of 0 and 1 for `arr[0]`.
Here `arr[1]` is set as 0. So we get the 2 outputs (00 and 01).

The function returns to `arr[n-1] = ‘1’`
`arr[2-1]` is set as 1 `(arr[2-1] = arr[1] = ‘1’)`

Again we call `binary(1);`
This time `arr[1]` is set as ‘1’ and thus we get 2 more outputs (10 and 11).

We have a total of 4 outputs on screen..(00, 01, 10, 11) These are all the strings of 2 bits.

Similarly, you can work around for `n = 3.`
`arr[2]` is set as ‘0’ and `binary(2)` is called. This produces (000, 010, 100, 110)
`arr[2]` is then set as ‘1’ and `binary(2)` is called. This produces (001, 011, 101, 111).
These are all the strings of 3 bits.

I hope this methodology makes it clear. Please feel free to ask anything else as well.

Answer (score 6):

This is the recursion flow for n=3,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with your description:

Now we call binary(1);
From the above explanation we know that binary(1) produces an output of 0 and 1 for arr[0]. Here arr[1] is set as 0. So we get the 2 outputs (00 and 01).

The output here would be 00 and 10 as arr[1] is set as 0.

Similarly when arr[1] is set as 1, the output would be 01 and 11.

I hope you agree